# Spark Scala where date is greater than

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create a function to get the last 4 days on data including today. Here's my function, what am I missing? When I run a test I got an empty table.

```
df.where(trunc(col("date"),"day") >= date_add(current_date(),-4))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `date_trunc` instead. `trunc` only supports month and year. Also note that `date_trunc` accepts arguments in the reverse order of `trunc`.

```
df.where(date_trunc("day",col("date")) >= date_add(current_date(),-4))
```